# Terraform state file in multiple backends

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Gitlab CI/CD to deploy to AWS with Terraform.

I would like to use the Gitlab REST API to store and lock/unlock my state.

To add some security and prevent any loss of my state file, I want also to backup my state file to an S3 bucket.

My question is: how to sync/update my state file present in my S3 bucket when my pipeline run a terraform apply and make changes to my AWS resources ?

Comment: Why not keep it in S3 only? Why do you need a local copy?

Comment: S3 does not support the lock mechanism I think and I don't want to use DynamoDB